# Send HttpRequest using post method with Ocaml Curl

Tags: http, post, curl, ocaml

I'm using Ocaml CURL to make http request to a server. I try to send it using the method post and I found this function (https://gist.github.com/zbroyar/1432555) :

```
let post ?(content_type = "text/html") url data =
let r,c = init_conn url in
Curl.set_post c true;
Curl.set_httpheader c [ "Content-Type: " ^ content_type ];
Curl.set_postfields c data;
Curl.set_postfieldsize c (String.length data);
Curl.perform c;
let rc = Curl.get_responsecode c in
Curl.cleanup c;
rc, (Buffer.contents r)
```

I understand that the value data contains the post values but in which form ? It should be "login=foo pass=bar" or "login=foo, pass=bar" ? Anyone has an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a POST request, it can send any kind of data using any form, that's why there is a `Content-Type` header to tell the server how to decode the data.
By default, this function will send HTML, if you want to use the [form encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type), replace `"text/html"` with `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`.